# Java Audio Stream (mp3spi lib), UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, audio, stream, classpath

I have seen multiple Stack Overflow questions regarding streaming MP3 streams (like Icecast). They all say to use the MP3SPI libraries, which I am. MP3SPI is for allowing support to `audio/mpeg` mime types. That's what my Icecast stream is. I have all three jar files in my classpath correctly, but while using the same code they provide in an example, I still get `UnsupportedAudioFileException`:

```
 javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input str
eam from input URL
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:
1153)
    at DJUtils.testPlay(DJUtils.java:16)
    at DJ.play(DJ.java:13)
    at DJ.init(DJ.java:4)
    at Loader.main(Loader.java:69)
```

Here's my code:

```
public static void testPlay(){
    try {
        AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL("http://localhost:8000/listen.m3u"));
        AudioInputStream din = null;
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                16,
                baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
        din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
        // Play now.
        rawplay(decodedFormat, din);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void rawplay(AudioFormat targetFormat, AudioInputStream din) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException{
    try{
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        SourceDataLine line = getLine(targetFormat);
        if (line != null)
        {
            // Start
            line.start();
            int nBytesRead = 0, nBytesWritten = 0;
            while (nBytesRead != -1)
            {
                nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length);
                if (nBytesRead != -1) nBytesWritten = line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
            // Stop
            line.drain();
            line.stop();
            line.close();
            din.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static SourceDataLine getLine(AudioFormat audioFormat) throws LineUnavailableException{
    try{
        SourceDataLine res = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        res = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        res.open(audioFormat);
        return res;
    }catch(LineUnavailableException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

My start script for this project:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath bin;lib/libs.jar;lib/graphics.jar;lib/mp3spi/mp3spi.jar;lib/mp3spi/jl.jar;lib/mp3spi/tritonus.jar; Loader
```

And my Icecast control panel says it's currently streaming `audio/mpeg`. I can access my stream fine by opening that URL in my code up in any media player. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you access that MP3 without streaming using the SPI?  Does the SPI rely on an input stream that can be repositioned?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - not sure what you mean, do you mean can I just play a regular MP3 that isn't being streamed? If that's what you mean, yes I actually can - I just tried. That's a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp3spi library as such does not consider m3u playlist file as a supported file.

Try using the real stream url used inside the m3u file. ie the url directly to the mp3 file or stream.

Check the function below. Its straight out of MpegAudioFileReader.java, mp3spi library uses to identify the format of the data stream you presented using URL. It doesn't recognize an m3u file. You can check the source if you want from http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/sources.html.

```
    public AudioFileFormat getAudioFileFormat(InputStream inputStream, long mediaLength) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
{
    if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out(">MpegAudioFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(InputStream inputStream, long mediaLength): begin");
    HashMap aff_properties = new HashMap();
    HashMap af_properties = new HashMap();
    int mLength = (int) mediaLength;
    int size = inputStream.available();
    PushbackInputStream pis = new PushbackInputStream(inputStream, MARK_LIMIT);
    byte head[] = new byte[22];
    pis.read(head);
    if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader)
    {
        TDebug.out("InputStream : " + inputStream + " =>" + new String(head));
    }

    // Check for WAV, AU, and AIFF, Ogg Vorbis, Flac, MAC file formats.
    // Next check for Shoutcast (supported) and OGG (unsupported) streams.
    if ((head[0] == 'R') && (head[1] == 'I') && (head[2] == 'F') && (head[3] == 'F') && (head[8] == 'W') && (head[9] == 'A') && (head[10] == 'V') && (head[11] == 'E'))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("RIFF/WAV stream found");
        int isPCM = ((head[21]<<8)&0x0000FF00) | ((head[20])&0x00000FF);
        if (weak == null)
        {
            if (isPCM == 1) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("WAV PCM stream found");
        }

    }
    else if ((head[0] == '.') && (head[1] == 's') && (head[2] == 'n') && (head[3] == 'd'))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("AU stream found");
        if (weak == null) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("AU stream found");
    }
    else if ((head[0] == 'F') && (head[1] == 'O') && (head[2] == 'R') && (head[3] == 'M') && (head[8] == 'A') && (head[9] == 'I') && (head[10] == 'F') && (head[11] == 'F'))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("AIFF stream found");
        if (weak == null) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("AIFF stream found");
    }
    else if (((head[0] == 'M') | (head[0] == 'm')) && ((head[1] == 'A') | (head[1] == 'a')) && ((head[2] == 'C') | (head[2] == 'c')))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("APE stream found");
        if (weak == null) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("APE stream found");
    }
    else if (((head[0] == 'F') | (head[0] == 'f')) && ((head[1] == 'L') | (head[1] == 'l')) && ((head[2] == 'A') | (head[2] == 'a')) && ((head[3] == 'C') | (head[3] == 'c')))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("FLAC stream found");
        if (weak == null) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("FLAC stream found");
    }
    // Shoutcast stream ?
    else if (((head[0] == 'I') | (head[0] == 'i')) && ((head[1] == 'C') | (head[1] == 'c')) && ((head[2] == 'Y') | (head[2] == 'y')))
    {
        pis.unread(head);
        // Load shoutcast meta data.
        loadShoutcastInfo(pis, aff_properties);
    }
    // Ogg stream ?
    else if (((head[0] == 'O') | (head[0] == 'o')) && ((head[1] == 'G') | (head[1] == 'g')) && ((head[2] == 'G') | (head[2] == 'g')))
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("Ogg stream found");
        if (weak == null) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("Ogg stream found");
    }
    // No, so pushback.
    else
    {
        pis.unread(head);
    }
    // MPEG header info.
    int nVersion = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nLayer = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nSFIndex = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nMode = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int FrameSize = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nFrameSize = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nFrequency = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nTotalFrames = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    float FrameRate = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int BitRate = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nChannels = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nHeader = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    int nTotalMS = AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED;
    boolean nVBR = false;
    AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = null;
    try
    {
        Bitstream m_bitstream = new Bitstream(pis);
        aff_properties.put("mp3.header.pos", new Integer(m_bitstream.header_pos()));
        Header m_header = m_bitstream.readFrame();
        // nVersion = 0 => MPEG2-LSF (Including MPEG2.5), nVersion = 1 => MPEG1
        nVersion = m_header.version();
        if (nVersion == 2) aff_properties.put("mp3.version.mpeg", Float.toString(2.5f));
        else aff_properties.put("mp3.version.mpeg", Integer.toString(2 - nVersion));
        // nLayer = 1,2,3
        nLayer = m_header.layer();
        aff_properties.put("mp3.version.layer", Integer.toString(nLayer));
        nSFIndex = m_header.sample_frequency();
        nMode = m_header.mode();
        aff_properties.put("mp3.mode", new Integer(nMode));
        nChannels = nMode == 3 ? 1 : 2;
        aff_properties.put("mp3.channels", new Integer(nChannels));
        nVBR = m_header.vbr();
        af_properties.put("vbr", new Boolean(nVBR));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.vbr", new Boolean(nVBR));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.vbr.scale", new Integer(m_header.vbr_scale()));
        FrameSize = m_header.calculate_framesize();
        aff_properties.put("mp3.framesize.bytes", new Integer(FrameSize));
        if (FrameSize < 0) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("Invalid FrameSize : " + FrameSize);
        nFrequency = m_header.frequency();
        aff_properties.put("mp3.frequency.hz", new Integer(nFrequency));
        FrameRate = (float) ((1.0 / (m_header.ms_per_frame())) * 1000.0);
        aff_properties.put("mp3.framerate.fps", new Float(FrameRate));
        if (FrameRate < 0) throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("Invalid FrameRate : " + FrameRate);
        if (mLength != AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED)
        {
            aff_properties.put("mp3.length.bytes", new Integer(mLength));
            nTotalFrames = m_header.max_number_of_frames(mLength);
            aff_properties.put("mp3.length.frames", new Integer(nTotalFrames));
        }
        BitRate = m_header.bitrate();
        af_properties.put("bitrate", new Integer(BitRate));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.bitrate.nominal.bps", new Integer(BitRate));
        nHeader = m_header.getSyncHeader();
        encoding = sm_aEncodings[nVersion][nLayer - 1];
        aff_properties.put("mp3.version.encoding", encoding.toString());
        if (mLength != AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED)
        {
            nTotalMS = Math.round(m_header.total_ms(mLength));
            aff_properties.put("duration", new Long((long) nTotalMS * 1000L));
        }
        aff_properties.put("mp3.copyright", new Boolean(m_header.copyright()));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.original", new Boolean(m_header.original()));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.crc", new Boolean(m_header.checksums()));
        aff_properties.put("mp3.padding", new Boolean(m_header.padding()));
        InputStream id3v2 = m_bitstream.getRawID3v2();
        if (id3v2 != null)
        {
            aff_properties.put("mp3.id3tag.v2", id3v2);
            parseID3v2Frames(id3v2, aff_properties);
        }
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out(m_header.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("not a MPEG stream:" + e.getMessage());
        throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("not a MPEG stream:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    // Deeper checks ?
    int cVersion = (nHeader >> 19) & 0x3;
    if (cVersion == 1)
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("not a MPEG stream: wrong version");
        throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("not a MPEG stream: wrong version");
    }
    int cSFIndex = (nHeader >> 10) & 0x3;
    if (cSFIndex == 3)
    {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioFileReader) TDebug.out("not a MPEG stream: wrong sampling rate");
        throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException("not a MPEG stream: wrong sampling rate");
    }
    // Look up for ID3v1 tag
    if ((size == mediaLength) && (mediaLength != AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED))
    {
        FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) inputStream;
        byte[] id3v1 = new byte[128];
        long bytesSkipped = fis.skip(inputStream.available() - id3v1.length);
        int read = fis.read(id3v1, 0, id3v1.length);
        if ((id3v1[0] == 'T') && (id3v1[1] == 'A') && (id3v1[2] == 'G'))
        {
            parseID3v1Frames(id3v1, aff_properties);
        }
    }
    AudioFormat format = new MpegAudioFormat(encoding, (float) nFrequency, AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED // SampleSizeInBits - The size of a sample
            , nChannels // Channels - The number of channels
            , -1 // The number of bytes in each frame
            , FrameRate // FrameRate - The number of frames played or recorded per second
            , true, af_properties);
    return new MpegAudioFileFormat(MpegFileFormatType.MP3, format, nTotalFrames, mLength, aff_properties);
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. I feat there isn't any "direct mp3" URL though, that's all I get, and even if I browse to that in the browser it opens up in Windows Media Player. How would I get this "direct mp3"? Thanks :)

Comment: Open the listen.m3u file in a text editor. That should contain the stream url inside.

Comment: WOW, thanks so much!! The direct stream turned out to be localhost:8000/listen (without the .m3u -.-). Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it did. One more quick question, can you explain how I would go about stopping the music? I would probably assume I would constantly check a variable in the rawplay() function, and if it equals something then stop & close all the connections. Is there a better way of doing this from another function in that class?

Comment: That is ok, i think. If you're using that kind of code in any application, i'd suggest you write the stopping and state changing code thread-safe. Check this: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18465.html . Especially look at the code used to pause and play. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I am actually running it in a thread. I'll check that out tomorrow since I have to go now. Thanks.